# Keep out zone of microSD card set footprint

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, sd, pcb-layers

I'm designing a PCB with Hirose microSD card set DM3AT-SF-PEJM5. In its [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2691071.pdf), page 3, there are several "no conductive traces" area, which are marked as "keep out" zone in the [footprint](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/DM3AT-SF-PEJM5/Hirose%20Electric%20Co%20Ltd/view-part/?ref=search&t=DM3AT-SF-PEJM5) I found.

My questions are:

- Why these areas are marked as "no conductive traces"?
- If I design a multilayer PCB, say 4 layers, and place the microSD card set on bottom layer, then I cannot route tracks in **any of the 4 layers** , or just in the **bottom layer**?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for not having conductive traces under the microSD card connector is because it is a push-push connector. This has moving mechanical parts which could touch the surface of the PCB during operation, meaning that these areas could be scratched over time and expose any conductive surfaces and potentially short circuit with the body of the connector.

Only the layer where this connector is mounted requires these keepouts.